# How to fetch all rows which will be removed on using cascading delete before delete query

Tags: sql, mysql, psql

What is the best approach to fetch all the rows, which will be deleted on cascade of primary key?

At present we know the list of tables which uses the primary key as foreign key, a simple select query can be used right now

On a large project,In future when a new table is added and a foreign key is created by using the primary key by any developer. They may miss the business logics which has to be done before cascade delete. So if there is auto discovery of affected rows, it can be handled accordingly.

I am looking for a some functionality in sql which says these rows will be affected before we initiate the delete query. Somehow the sql engine maintains the mapping of relationship to delete cascadingly.

Can we somehow leverge the cascade delete relationship to fetch all the rows in relationship in select query.

Edit:

The requirement is to show the users which rows will be deleted at any point of time.

I am looking for a solution in sql so that this use case need not be achieved using another backend language even if schema changes are being made in future.

Comment: No such instrument. Especially while taking into account that FK may refer on any uniquely indexed expression, not only on primary key.

Comment: "*If we know the list of tables which uses the primary key as foreign key, a simple select query can be used.*" that simple query would identify the affected rows (`select * from x where fk=value`). So I don't understand what the actual question  is.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql (psql)?

Comment: How come this question is upvoted?!? It's not very clear, or prove much effort.

Comment: @AdrianMaxwell To add more clarity to question. 

At the time of writing we may know the list of tables so that we can handle the business logic using select query with the known list of tables.

In future  when someone adds new table with the foreign key constraints they may forgot to add that table in the known table list which will make the business logics to fail. 

So as mentioned in question. I am looking for a solution to auto discover rows in any number of tables without maintaining the list of tables somwhere.

Comment: @jarlh To answer your question this is not specific to any database. I am looking for programming techniques to solve the use case. 

Always you can ask for clarification if YOU DON'T UNDERSTAND. Instead of blaming the upvotes and efforts put on question

Comment: A solution would also need to track cascading deletes that cause other cascading deletes (e.g. deleting a row in `tableA` which deletes 2 rows in `tableB` which is referenced by `tableC` causing more deletes). Did you try running the delete in a transaction & checking the session variables and then issuing a `ROLLBACK`?

Comment: The answer is to revert the recent schema changes. Go back to a stable version and start all over. Don't try to adjust code to avoid consequences of a bad schema change.

Comment: And if you don't trust the developers, don't allow on delete cascade fk's.

Comment: @TheScrumMeister Yes exactly that's what required,  Your idea may work with "DELETE RETURNING" in psql. Can you post this a answer so it can be upvoted

Comment: @jarlh It was never about Schema Changes or Trust in developers.

My need is to show to users which rows are being deleted by cascade. As i said right now i will know exactly using my business logic so that i can show it to users.

In future, when schema changes are being made.. They need to rewrite the business logic to achieve the same functionality

My required solution will eliminate developer time for future developers rewriting business logics to show all the data being deleted

Answer (score 0):

A crude solution I could think of is to probe MySQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` to find the primary key of the table in question, then find all tables that reference that primary key. Here is an example query to determine the primary key of [`employees` database](https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db), `employees` table:

```
SELECT K.TABLE_SCHEMA, K.TABLE_NAME, K.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
    WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY' 
    AND K.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    AND K.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND K.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
    AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'employees' 
    AND C.TABLE_NAME = 'employees' 
);
```

| TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| employees | employees | emp_no |

Then the query to find all tables that reference `employees` database, `employees` table, `emp_no` column as the foreign key:

```
SELECT K.TABLE_SCHEMA, K.TABLE_NAME, K.COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE AS K
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS C
    WHERE C.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
    AND K.CONSTRAINT_NAME = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    AND K.TABLE_SCHEMA = C.TABLE_SCHEMA 
    AND K.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME
)
AND K.REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = 'employees'
AND K.REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'employees'
AND K.REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME = 'emp_no'
```

| TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| employees | dept_emp | emp_no |
| employees | dept_manager | emp_no |
| employees | salaries | emp_no |
| employees | titles | emp_no |

You now have a list of all tables that reference the employee table. Based on the above information, you can assemble a script that creates select statements for the employee that will be deleted and the rows in four related tables.

**Unfortunately, the information schema does not tell you if the constraint has `on delete cascade`**.

Comment: This will work if only if relationship is in one level 

Consider cascading deletes triggering other cascading deletes in which my primary key is not directly involved. 

We need to identify those too.

Comment: You repeat the process with the 4 tables you got on step 2.